# Print top 10 users who post lots of questions and lots of answers of a Web Forum

Tags: java, performance, parallel-processing, bigdata, distributed-system

I want to compare people who post lots of questions vs lots of answers in a Web Forum. I need to print out the top 10 users who ask questions and also who answer the questions. I have written a script that generates the list. But it takes too long and uses too much memory and is inefficient.

The code which I have written is using HashMap. The .xml file of the users and the posts is very big. The actual data is around 5-6 gigabytes.

I need to know the best way by which I can improve the time, efficiency and performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approach :

**1) Updates from time to time** : You dont show "actual" value, you count it from time to time (even once a month, if it is enough to achieve your goals) and store the result. You only show the result.

**2) Using redundant structures** : You have stored same information twice but differently, because each one helps you to quickly find something else. For example, if you often want to show sum of all posts in your forum and you dont want count it one by one, you can have extra column, which is updated whenever new post is added which stores the total number of posts.

Note that you have to be careful with it, because it can lead to inconsistence of data, if you do something wrong (but as long as you use your redundant structures just for some fancy bussiness, like showing TOP 5, it is just fine)

Comment: I already have the data.. If I create another column now, I will still have to traverse the whole data.. If I use HashMap, the 5-6GB data will come in memory and slow down the processing which will reduce the time.. again I do not want this to happen..

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is the heavy hitters algorithm. It is très cool. It is a one-pass algorithm; and can be updated live or done afterwards.

Every time a user asks a question or posts an answer, you notify the data structure, which keeps track of the top k "heavy hitters." It does get a bit fuzzy around the time one of the users drops out of the top k.

Here are some resources:

- [the research paper](https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/download/attachments/117571610/2005-23.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1263594781000) describing the idea
- [a blog post](http://boundary.com/blog/2013/05/14/approximate-heavy-hitters-the-spacesaving-algorithm/) - the first hit on google for "heavy hitters algorithm"

Comment: I am thinking of creating threads which are equal to the number of my cores (8). Each thread will process a fixed chunk size (say 512 KB) and store the answer in a HashMap. In this way, all the data will not be in memory and it will save memory and speed up the process. But I am not sure whether I can do this in java. How do I run multiple threads on my cores? Do I need to worry about this?

Answer (score 0):

Add two columns to your users table: questions_count, answers_count. Instead of bringing it all into memory, just go through each message and determine if it is a question or an answer and then update the user that posted that message. Update your forum software to do the analysis when a message is submitted so that after you have done the first pass, the forum will just keep the data updated for you. With your two columns, it becomes two simple queries to get the top ten users that ask and answer questions.

If you want to get fancy, and track who is asking and answering in different time spans("Who were the top 10 question askers this week?" or "Who answered the most questions this year?"), then you will want to create a new table that tracks `user_id, message_id, message_type(question|answer), timestamp`. This will allow you to answer most of those types of questions with a single SQL call.